# How do I enable devToken for a StreamChat?

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to initialize a new chat using a devToken to allow client-side generated tokens by coding the following inside an async function:

```
    let chatClient = await new StreamChat(apiKey);

    await chatClient.updateAppSettings({
      disable_auth_checks: true,
    });

    await chatClient.setUser(
      {
        id: 'user-0',
        name: random-user-name,
      },
      chatClient.devToken('user-0'),
    );
```

but am getting the error that "Both secret and user tokens are not set", despite using a devToken. The error stops the code from running once it hits

```
await chatClient.updateAppSettings({
      disable_auth_checks: true,
    });
```

, which is supposed to allow me to use the .devToken in place of a userToken.

So I added my secretKey to new StreamChat

```
let chatClient = await new StreamChat(apiKey, secretKey);
```

however, then I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of null at JWTServerToken" right after that line runs.

And if I try to generate a userToken and replace `chatClient.devToken('user-0')` with userToken like this

```
    let userToken = await chatClient.createToken("user-0");
```

I get the error "Error: tokens can only be created server-side using the API Secret", which is what I was trying to avoid.

Does anyone know how to correctly enable .devTokens so that the chatClient can be set without generating a token server-side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done via the dashboard. First, make sure your app is in development mode.

[image: dashboard app with options dropdown and edit button highlighted]

[image: update app screen with development and submit buttons highlighted]

Then, navigate to the app's chat overview page and enable "Disable Auth Checks". Hit save.

[image: app dashboard with disable auth checks and save button highlighted]

Comment: Hello Matheus, thanks for your response. I'm still getting the error that both secret and user tokens are not set, which is triggered when I try to set disable_auth_checks: true in chatClient.updateAppSettings. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @RebeccaLambert Have you got any solution for this issue?